# Get common values in three vectors at least repeated once between vectors

Tags: r

I want to compare an undetermined number of vectors and get the common values in at least two of them.

As an example, let’s just use three vectors:

```
x <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
y <- c(3,6,8,9,4)
z <- c(2,3,4,5,7,9)

Reduce(intersect, list(x,y,z))

# or

intersect(x, intersect(y,z))

[1] 3 9
```

Expected result is:

```
[1] 3 4 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

We may `stack` a named `list` to two column data.frame, get the `table`, check if the row wise sum is greater than or equal to 2, return the `names` that are TRUE for those

```
names(which(rowSums(table(stack(list(x= x, y = y, z = z))) > 0) >= 2))
[1] "3" "4" "5" "7" "9"
```

---

If we want to use pairwise `intersect` for all combinations, use `combn` and then `Reduce` with `union`

```
sort(Reduce(union, combn(list(x, y, z), 2,
    FUN = function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = FALSE)))
[1] 3 4 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the vectors in one large vector:

```
vec <- unlist(list(x, y, z))
```

Or, if you may have duplicates within a single contributing vector:

```
vec <- unlist(lapply(list(x, y, z), unique))
```

Then, subset based on presence of duplicates (and sort if needed):

```
sort(unique(vec[duplicated(vec)]))
```

**Output**

```
[1] 3 4 5 7 9
```